# Writing txt files to external flash Universal Windows/Windows IoT

Tags: wpf, uwp, windows-iot-core-10

As mentioned in other posts it is only possible to write pictures, videos and music to an external flash with Windows Devices (In my case a Raspberry Pi 3 B using Windows IoT).

Thankfull to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859872/writing-files-to-external-flash-drive-in-windows-universal) I am able to write my data to a jpg. [Mike Leonhardi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6697498/mike-leonardi) wrote that he was able to write also a txt file by modifying the capabilities.

Can someone tell me which modifications have to be done?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Windows IoT Raspberry Pi 3 c# Create .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46301900/windows-iot-raspberry-pi-3-c-sharp-create-txt-file)

Here you can find the modifications which have to be done.

Instead of .txt you can also use .csv to write a csv-file to your external flash.